# Showing month and year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that results in a timestamp value along with certain other calculations.

The result looks something like below -

```
City       DateTime                            Value
London     2009-01-01 00:00:00.000000           22
New York   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000           33
...         ...                                 ...
```

Is there any way to obtain the dateTime column with month and year - something like `Jan-2009` and `Jan-2010` instead of entire timestamp. I don't want to use the case statement.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

```
t=# select now(),to_char(now(),'Mon-YYYY');
              now              | to_char
-------------------------------+----------
 2017-09-20 07:49:34.360483+00 | Sep-2017
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

> to_char(timestamp, text)

and
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE
for formats

Comment: I have got downvote because I used `timestamptz` instead of `timezone` in my example or because the question should not be answered?.. Or because it is unclear? Please comment when downvote - I would gladly elaborate  it. Minus two points is not scary enough to stop doing smth wrong - explain what is wrong instead

Answer (score 0):

the postgresql data type formating function `to_char` can solve this problem. It takes 2 arguments, a timestamp and a template pattern string, and return a date string according to the provided pattern. see [Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html) for the complete pattern list.

You can try something like the following:

`select city, to_char(your_date_field, 'Mon-YYYY'), value from your_table`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.